# Убрать срабатывание мыши при срабатывании тачскрина unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть одна удобная штука в Unity

```
Input.GetMouseButton(0)
```

Возвращает true и при прикосновении к тачскрину. Как это отключить?

Comment: Отключить - никак. В [руководстве](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/MobileInput.html) рекомендуется переходить на TouchInput. Если вам нужно использовать универсальный метод для обработки ввода, но отделить мышь от тача, абстрагируйтесь от платформы.

В случае с Unity можно описать класс и при загрузке игры писать в его экземпляр специфичные для платформы и конкретного устройства значения. Конкретно для ввода можно завести делегат, которая будет возвращать координаты, например.

Попробуйте расписать, что конкретно вы пытаетесь сделать - может быть, есть варианты получше

Comment: @eastwing
Нужен ввод для Unity, который на всех платформах будет работать с клавиатурой и мышкой. Чтобы зажмешь - и тянулись спрайты за ним по экрану. Просто когда пишешь два разных методы, один для тача, с FingerID,чтобы корректно отрабатывало пальцы, всё работает, а тут на тебе - метод мышки спокойно перехватывает управление, т.к. ему совершенно без разницы на FIngerID - у мышки его просто нет.

Comment: Я не очень понял, что значит "на всех платформах будет работать с клавиатурой и мышкой" - и на мобилах тоже? Но вообще, сдаётся мне, без абстрагирования вам никак

Comment: @eastwing
Да, на мобилах тоже. Чтобы при подключении по OTG - работало

Comment: Я сейчас не могу проверить, нет Юнити под рукой. Вы пишете, что у мыши просто нет FIngerID - это можно как-то зафиксировать в коде? Например, при использовании мыши, FIngerID = null. Если можно  - вот вам и фильтр

Comment: @eastwing 
По умолчанию FingerID и так стоит -1, пока не используется тач. Но 

`Input.GetMouseButton(0)`

при прикосновении возвращает true даже так. В итоге там где должна работать мышка - тачпад работает тоже.

Comment: Итак, если я всё правильно понял (и вспомнил), то FingerID основывается на массиве Input.Touches, который зависит от касаний к тачскрину. Таким образом, если щёлкнуть мышью, FingerID не будет затронут, а вот если нажать на тачскрин - будет, независимо от того, каким методом было обработано касание. То есть, **по идее**, по FingerID можно отсеивать касания проверкой условия, например так: if (Touch.fingerId == -1) {//обработка мыши}